# Not able to grant my custom content provider permission in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-6.0-marshmallow

I was developing a content provider app.
In the manifest of that app I was placed a provider element In the application tag.
The following are the code

```
<provider
            android:name=".PlatesContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tag.custom_contentproviderdemo.Plates"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:readPermission="PlatesContentProvider._READ_PERMISSION"
            android:writePermission="PlatesContentProvider._WRITE_PERMISSION"
            android:exported="true" >
```

I also developed another app namely CPClient. It will read/write data to the content provider mentioned above.
I was declared   element in its manifest file.

The following are the code

```
<uses-permission android:name="PlatesContentProvider._READ_PERMISSION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="PlatesContentProvider._WRITE_PERMISSION"/>
```

In the launcher activity of the CPClient I was checked for this permission .If it is not granted means I will  request for permission.
But in requesting permission it does not shown request permission dialog and always permission is not granted.

The following are the code

```
private final String permissionsRequired="PlatesContentProvider._READ_PERMISSION";
    private final String permissionsRequired2= "PlatesContentProvider._WRITE_PERMISSION";
    private String[] permissions=new String[]{permissionsRequired,permissionsRequired2};    
public void process()
        {
            checkPermission();

            if(!permission_granted)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not granted.Requesing permission....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                requestPermission1();return;
            }
            else
            {
                bindWidgetEvents();  //After permission granted I will perform some process
                Log.d(TAG,"Permission granted");return;
            }
        }

        public void checkPermission()
        {
            int permit=this.checkSelfPermission(permissionsRequired);

            if(permit== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "permission granted");
                permission_granted=true;return;
            }
            else
                Log.d(TAG,"permission not granted");
            permission_granted=false;
        }

        public void requestPermission1()
        {
            //boolean show=this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRequired);
            //Log.d(TAG,"need to show = "+show);


            Thread thread=new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"B4 call request permission");
                    requestPermissions(permissions,CONTENT_PROVIDER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                    Log.d(TAG,"after call request permission");
                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions1[], int[] grantResults)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult. req code="+requestCode);
            if(requestCode==CONTENT_PROVIDER_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Content provider permsion request code");
                if(grantResults==null)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"grant results is null");
                    Toast.makeText(this,"UnKnown error happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                int grant_results_size=grantResults.length;
                Log.d(TAG,"Grant result size="+grant_results_size);
                if(grant_results_size<1)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"grant results size is <1");
                    Toast.makeText(this,"UnKnown error happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if(grantResults[0]!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Permission not granted");
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Read Permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if(grantResults[1]!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Permission not granted");
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Write Permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG,"Permission granted");

                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bindWidgetEvents();

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"not a Content provider permsion request code");
            }
        }
```

The following are the android sdk details
my target and min sdk version is 23 in the both content provider app and my CPClient.

I don't know where I will go wrong?

All are welcome to give their ideas.

Comment: Have you declared `<permission>` elements for those custom permissions in the manifest for the app with the Provider? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30097365

Comment: im not added.plz update the sample code for that

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: im not added  permission element .send me details where i need to add in the manifest.its very usefull for me

Comment: The answer below shows where to put them. They go outside of the `<application>` tags in the manifest for the app with the `<provider>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare your permissions in 'manifest' block as well as in provider.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="your.package">

    <permission
        android:name="PlatesContentProvider._READ_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <permission
        android:name="PlatesContentProvider._WRITE_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name=".PlatesContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.tag.custom_contentproviderdemo.Plates"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:readPermission="PlatesContentProvider._READ_PERMISSION"
            android:writePermission="PlatesContentProvider._WRITE_PERMISSION"
            android:exported="true" >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Its not working for .In the client app when I call requestPermissions it does not show any dialog and  always return permission is not granted.

Comment: If you declare this permissions as 'normal' level protection, they are automatically granted. You can also use 'signature' or 'signatureOrSystem' protection levels. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html.